# how to conditionally style links in Nuxt/Vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building a Nuxt app and am having trouble with conditional styling. What I'm trying to do is apply a different background color to the active link depending on what page it is. I know I can use `.nuxt-link-exact-active` to style the active link, but I'm stuck on how to make that different on each page.

I have the links in a component that gets rendered on each page. I've tried using `.nuxt-link-exact-active` at the page level, but it doesn't get picked up.

Here's what I've got so far, which does change the styling depending on the page, but it does it for *all* the links, and I only want it on the *active* link. Please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks!

```
<template>
  <nav class="flex-container flex-column mt-1">
    <NuxtLink to="/about" class="link" :class="classObject">about</NuxtLink>
    <div class="mt-1 flex-container">
      <NuxtLink to="/projects" class="link" :class="classObject"
        >projects</NuxtLink
      >
    </div>
    <div class="mt-1 flex-container">
      <NuxtLink to="/contact" class="link" :class="classObject"
        >contact</NuxtLink
      >
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // apply current route name as a class to the matching div
  computed: {
    classObject() {
      return {
        about: this.$route.name === 'about',
        projects: this.$route.name === 'projects',
        contact: this.$route.name === 'contact',
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.about {
  background-color: $near-white;
}

.projects {
  background-color: $blue;
}

.contact {
  background-color: $yellow;
}
</style>
```

[illustration of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuRZI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing `.nuxt-link-exact-active` at the page level, change it in the layout.

So for example, in `layouts/default.vue`:

```
<style>
.nuxt-link-exact-active {
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for getting back to me— that works as far as styling the current page's link, but it still styles it the same way on each page. I edited my question to include a picture of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution— not sure if it's the best way, but it works. Each link is now preceded by a `div` that only gets rendered on the corresponding page, otherwise a link is rendered.

```
<template>
  <nav class="flex-container flex-column mt-1">
    <div v-if="currentPageName === 'about'" class="box about">
      <h2>about</h2>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <NuxtLink to="/about" class="link">about</NuxtLink>
    </div>
    <div v-if="currentPageName === 'projects'" class="box projects">
      <h2>projects</h2>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <NuxtLink to="/projects" class="link">projects</NuxtLink>
    </div>
    <div v-if="currentPageName === 'contact'" class="box contact">
      <h2>contact</h2>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <NuxtLink to="/contact" class="link">contact</NuxtLink>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    currentPageName() {
      return this.$route.name
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.about {
  background-color: $near-white;
}

.projects {
  background-color: $blue;
}

.contact {
  background-color: $yellow;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to check if the path is active or not is $nuxt.$route.path.

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li>
          <nuxt-link :to="links[0].path" :class="{'bg-black text-white': links[0].path == path }">{{ links[0].name }}</nuxt-link>
          <nuxt-link :to="links[1].path" :class="{secondStyle: links[1].path == path }">{{ links[1].name }}</nuxt-link>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
    
<script>
    export default {
        name: "Header",
        data() {
          return {
            path: null,
            links: [
              {path: "/link1", name: "Link 1"},
              {path: "/link2", name: "Link 2"}
            ],
          };
        },
        mounted() {
          this.path = $nuxt.$route.path;
        },
    };
</script>
```